# How to query a column in a table twice with different record value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in a table name ActionFlag where it has values such as "N", "R", and "A"
but when I try to query this statement nothing appears?

```
select tblFtpTrans.*,tblLocs.unit from tblFtpTrans left join tblLocs on 
tblFtpTrans.location=tblLocs.location where tblFtpTrans.id>0 and actiondate>='2020-06-01' and 
actiondate<='2020-07-30' and actionflag='N' AND ActionFlag='A'
```

Sample Data

```
NumId   WorkId  EightId Num ActionFlag
24803   17944   7683    0   N
24804   17940   5076    0   A
24805   17896   7684    0   A
24806   17904   7685    0   B
24807   17868   7686    0   R
```

This is what I want

```
NumId   WorkId  EightId Num ActionFlag
24803   17944   7683    0   N
24804   17940   5076    0   A
24805   17896   7684    0   A
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results woudl help.

Comment: Updated the following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `in`:

```
select t.*, l.unit
from tblFtpTrans t left join
     tblLocs l
     on t.location = l.location
where t.id > 0 and
      actiondate >= '2020-06-01' and 
      actiondate <= '2020-07-30' and
      actionflag in ('N', 'A')
```

Comment: I updated what I want im writing this in classic asp so Im making checkboxes when I select a box it has one of the action flag values and Im sql it in the table

Comment: @Sdot2323 . . . I revised the answer.  You just want `or` or `in`.